# How to delete first line of XML file using XMLDocument in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am reading an XML file in C# using `XMLDocument`. My code goes like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlSourceFile);
```

First line of my XML document is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I have to delete this line. How should I?

Comment: My guess is that first line is needed for the `XmlDocument` to properly read the file, like know which encoding to use. Any reason why you couldn't delete that line as if it was a standard text file?

Comment: Why do you want to delete this *processing instruction*?

Comment: It's not a line, it's an element. And it harms no-one, so why bother? Your problem is your requirement.

Comment: I have given you an answer, but I'm just wondering now... is it before or after you load the document that you want to remove that declaration? You didn't specify.

Comment: @all - I want to remove that because I have to save it in database and afterwards when I fetch that again, I have to again add that line

Comment: and why cant you have that line in the database with the rest of the xml? what problem does it cause?

Comment: Example usage - Inserting into XML native 2012 column type. I receive XML from many institutions/corporations to a single database. I have XML that is sent with instruction of UTF-8 but contains characters (Such as "Numero" character) which throws a fit. If UTF-8 is in the declaration, it passes that to SQL, if no declaration occurs, it assumes UTF-8, but attempts to figure it out if it fails.

Comment: Thus, I attempt to save using the encoding given, but upon failure, remove the declaration for sql to figure it out.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't see why you would want to remove that. But if it is required, you could try this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("something");

foreach (XmlNode node in doc)
{
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    {
        doc.RemoveChild(node);
    }
}
```

or with LINQ:

```
var declarations = doc.ChildNodes.OfType<XmlNode>()
    .Where(x => x.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    .ToList();

declarations.ForEach(x => doc.RemoveChild(x));
```

Comment: I need to do this because I need to compare two XML strings, one of which has the XML header while the other one does not (the second one does not because it was extracted from a larger XML document).

Comment: Sometimes we need hacks. I also needed to remove the xml declaration for a saml request. Thank you

Comment: This step is required to create a valid samlp:AuthnRequest

Answer (score 12):

I needed to have an XML serialized string without the declaration header so the following code worked for me.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
    Indent = true,
    OmitXmlDeclaration = true, // this makes the trick :)
    IndentChars = "  ",
    NewLineChars = "\n",
    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Replace
};
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb, settings)) {
    doc.Save(writer);
}
return sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively you can use this;

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
if (xmlDoc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
    xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);
```

Answer (score 4):

A very quick and easier solution is using the [`DocumentElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `XmlDocument` class:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlSourceFile);
Console.Out.Write(doc.DocumentElement.OuterXml);
```

Comment: Most elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

I understand the need to eliminate the XML Declaration; I'm working on a script that alters the content of an application's `preferences.xml`, and the application doesn't read the file properly if the declaration is there (not sure why the developers decided to omit the XML declaration).

Instead of messing around with the XML any longer, I just created a `removeXMLdeclaration()` method that reads the XML file and removes the first line, then rewrites it back simply using streamreaders/writers. It's lightning fast, and works great! I just call the method after I've done all my XML alteration to clean the file up once and for all.

Here is the code:

```
public void removeXMLdeclaration()
    {
        try
        {
            //Grab file
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(xmlPath);

            //Read first line and do nothing (i.e. eliminate XML declaration)
            sr.ReadLine();
            string body = null;
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            while(line != null) // read file into body string
            {
                body += line + "\n";
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }
            sr.Close(); //close file

            //Write all of the "body" to the same text file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(xmlPath, body);
        }
        catch (Exception e3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e3.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to close this file use file stream.

```
public void xyz ()
{
       FileStream file = new FileStream(xmlfilepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
       doc.load(xmlfilepath);

      // do whatever you want to do with xml file

      //then close it by 
      file.close();
      File.Delete(xmlfilepath);
}
```